# how to log url which caused error in node.js express

Tags: node.js, express

When error occurs on `node.js express` site its log file don't show url on which error occured. It shows url of previous request. But to debug error I need to know url which caused an error.

```
GET /some/local/url?page=2 200 339ms - 68b  # previus request

http.js:704                                 # error request without url
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
  at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:704:11)
```

I use [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) and `nginx`. So how to make it show url which caused an error in log file?

Comment: You might be able to use [Error handling middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling)

Comment: thanx @dc5, but when using  [Error handling middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling)  I need call `next()` everywhere I expect error, but error always jumps out where you don't expect it

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple code to capture error when url goes incorrect:

```
var http = require("http");

var options = {
    host : "www.abc.com/get/something"
};

var request = http.request(options, function(req) {
    // DO WITH REQUEST
});
request.on('error', function(err) {
     console.log(err.domain); // domain url
     console.log(request.url); // URL of req made 
    // DO SOMETHING WITH ERROR
});
```

Comment: Thanx @Ashwin, but I use [express](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.route) and my request handler differs from your example: `app.get('/user/:id?', function(req, res){ console.log(req.route);});`. So can't figure out how to use `request.on` here